# Delete older than month AWS EC2 snapshots

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is this below given command will work or not to delete older than month AWS EC2 Snapshot.

aws describe-snapshots | grep -v (date +%Y-%m-) | grep snap- | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -n 1 -t aws delete-snapshot

Comment: Why don't you add `--dry-run` to the `delete-snapshot` command and test it yourself?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your command won't work mostly because of a typo: `aws describe-snapshots` should be `aws ec2 describe-snapshots`.

Anyway, you can do this without any other tools than aws:

```bash
snapshots_to_delete=$(aws ec2 describe-snapshots --owner-ids xxxxxxxxxxxx --query 'Snapshots[?StartTime<=`2017-02-15`].SnapshotId' --output text)
echo "List of snapshots to delete: $snapshots_to_delete"

# actual deletion
for snap in $snapshots_to_delete; do
  aws ec2 delete-snapshot --snapshot-id $snap
done
```

Make sure you always know what are you deleting. By `echo $snap`, for example.
Also, adding `--dry-run` to `aws ec2 delete-snapshot` can show you that there are no errors in request.

---

**Edit:**

There are two things to pay attention at in the first command:

1. `--owner-ids` - you account unique id. Could easily be found manually in top right corner of AWS Console: `Support->Support Center->Account Number xxxxxxxxxxxx`
2. `--query` - JMESPath query which gets only snapshots created later than specified date (e.g.: 2017-02-15): `` Snapshots[?StartTime>=`2017-02-15`].SnapshotId ``

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but ?StartTime>=`2017-02-15` will select the snapshots NEWER than 2017-02-15 right? So I think this wants to be <= rather than >=.

Comment: This only gives me a single snapshot ID at a time... was that to be expected? I'm trying to delete several thousands of snapshots this way

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris $snapshots_to_delete variable should contain a long string of snapshots id separated by whitespaces

Comment: Getting *`illegal token value`* when running this? Your awscli version is probably too old.  upgrading to 1.16 worked for me [(maybe JMESPath is in > 1.2)](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.rst#user-content-id681). 

Also be sure your pip is greater than 2.9 or you will get a warning for *`SNIMissingWarning`*.

Comment: I edited the answer to fix issues reported by ThePerson and Cyril Duchon-Doris

Answer (score 4):

+1 to @roman-zhuzha for getting me close.  i did have trouble when `$snapshots_to_delete` didn't parse into a long string of snapshots separated by whitespaces.

this script, below, does parse them into a long string of snapshot ids separated by whitespaces on my Ubuntu (trusty) 14.04 in bash with awscli 1.16:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

dry_run=1
echo_progress=1

d=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d' -d '1 month ago')
if [ $echo_progress -eq 1 ]
then
  echo "Date of snapshots to delete (if older than): $d"
fi

snapshots_to_delete=$(aws ec2 describe-snapshots \
    --owner-ids xxxxxxxxxxxxx \
    --output text \
    --query "Snapshots[?StartTime<'$d'].SnapshotId" \
)
if [ $echo_progress -eq 1 ]
then
  echo "List of snapshots to delete: $snapshots_to_delete"
fi


for oldsnap in $snapshots_to_delete; do

  # some $oldsnaps will be in use, so you can't delete them
  # for "snap-a1234xyz" currently in use by "ami-zyx4321ab"
  # (and others it can't delete) add conditionals like this

  if [ "$oldsnap" = "snap-a1234xyz" ] ||
     [ "$oldsnap" = "snap-c1234abc" ]
  then
    if [ $echo_progress -eq 1 ]
    then
       echo "skipping $oldsnap known to be in use by an ami"
    fi
    continue
  fi

  if [ $echo_progress -eq 1 ]
  then
     echo "deleting $oldsnap"
  fi

  if [ $dry_run -eq 1 ]
  then
    # dryrun will not actually delete the snapshots
    aws ec2 delete-snapshot --snapshot-id $oldsnap --dry-run
  else
    aws ec2 delete-snapshot --snapshot-id $oldsnap
  fi
done
```

---

Switch these variables as necesssary:

```
dry_run=1           # set this to 0 to actually delete
echo_progress=1     # set this to 0 to not echo stmnts
```

Change the `date -d` string to a human readable version of the number of days, months, or years back you want to delete "older than":

```
d=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d' -d '15 days ago')  # half a month
```

Find your account id and update these XXXX's to that number:

```
    --owner-ids xxxxxxxxxxxxx \
```

Here is an example of where you can find that number:

[image]

---

If running this in a cron, you only want to see errors and warnings.  A frequent warning will be that there are snapshots in use.  The two *example snapshot* id's (snap-a1234xyz, snap-c1234abc) are ignored since they would otherwise print something like:

> An error occurred (InvalidSnapshot.InUse) when calling the DeleteSnapshot operation: The snapshot snap-a1234xyz is currently in use by ami-zyx4321ab

See the comments near "snap-a1234xyx" example snapshot id for how to handle this output.

---

[And don't forget to check on the handy examples and references in the 1.16 aws cli describe-snapshots manual](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-snapshots.html).

Answer (score 3):

you can use 'self' in '--owner-ids' and delete the snapshots created before a specific date (e.g. 2018-01-01) with this one-liner command:

```
for i in $(aws ec2 describe-snapshots --owner-ids self --query 'Snapshots[?StartTime<=`2018-01-01`].SnapshotId' --output text); do echo Deleting $i; aws ec2 delete-snapshot --snapshot-id $i; sleep 1; done;
```

Comment: This is really useful, we can log exceptions. The new Life Cycle AMI generation keeps x AMI's by deregistering the oldest one (Like GDG or Log Rotate) but the snapshots are not deleted ($$$).  Loathe to update cli frequently as so much breaks, especially with text output.

Answer (score 0):

Date condition must be within Parenthesis ()

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots \
    --owner-ids 012345678910 \
    --query "Snapshots[?(StartTime<='2020-03-31')].[SnapshotId]"
```