# Substituting a variable in a command that needs to contain a backtick inside single quotes

Tags: bash, aws-cli

I was trying to write a simple bash script to automatically delete EBS snapshots older than 30 days using the script suggested in the existing question [Delete older than month AWS EC2 snapshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42835307/delete-older-than-month-aws-ec2-snapshots/52653545)

However, I cannot get it run correctly or pick up the date as a variable:

Original code looks like this:

```
snapshots_to_delete=($(aws ec2 describe-snapshots --owner-ids xxxxxxxxxxxx --query 'Snapshots[?StartTime>=`2017-02-15`].SnapshotId' --output text))
```

I want it to run something like:

```
DATE=`date --date="3 month ago" +%Y-%m-%d`

snapshots_to_delete=($(aws ec2 describe-snapshots --owner-ids xxxxxxxxxxxx --query 'Snapshots[?StartTime>=$DATE].SnapshotId' --output text))
```

I've tried every combination of `[`, `"`, `\`, `/`, `` ` ``, and `'` I can think of to get it working, but no luck so far!

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to fix this is to end the single-quotes *after* the backtick that needs to be literal, put your expansion in a double-quoted expansion, and then switch back to a single-quoted context for the rest of the command:

```
date=$(date --date="3 month ago" +%Y-%m-%d)

IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a snapshots_to_delete < <(
  aws ec2 describe-snapshots \
    --owner-ids xxxxxxxxxxxx \
    --query 'Snapshots[?StartTime>=`'"$date"'`].SnapshotId' && printf '\0'
)
declare -p snapshots_to_delete >&2 # print the resulting value
```

Why write it this way?

- In `` 'Snapshots[?StartTime>=`'"$date"'`].SnapshotId' ``, there are three distinct substrings, each quoted a different way, with syntactical quote characters transitioning between quoting styles:

  1. The first character, `'`, starts a single-quoted context; it is shell syntax, not data.
  2. `` Snapshots[?StartTime>=` `` is the first substring; because it's inside *single quotes*, it isn't modified in any way (and the backtick isn't treated as special to the shell), and thus becomes part of a string in the `aws` command's argument vector exactly as-is.
  3. The next character, another `'`, ends that single-quoted context; it too is shell syntax, not data.
  4. The next character, `"`, is shell syntax which starts a double-quoted context. This is because in a double-quoted context, parameter expansions are guaranteed not to undergo string-splitting or glob expansion.
  5. `$date`, inside a double-quoted context, is the second segment that expands to contain a substring -- replaced with the named variable's value. The result of this expansion, being in double quotes, is treated as data with no further parsing steps applied.
  6. The next `"` is syntax which ends the double-quoted context.
  7. The next `'` is syntax which begins a new single-quoted context.
  8. `` `].SnapshotId ``, the third substring treated as data, is given as a literal inside that single-quoted context; because of that context, the backtick literal is passed to `aws` exactly as-is.
  9. The final `'` is syntax which ends the single-quoted context.
- Using a lower-case variable name for `date` is in line with POSIX guidelines specifying that all-caps names be used for variables meaningful to the shell and OS-provided tools, whereas names with at least one character are reserved for application use. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that shell and environment variables share a namespace.
- Replacing `snapshots_to_delete=( $(...) )` is for reasons described in [BashPitfalls #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29):

  - Using `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a snapshots_to_delete` causes stdin to be split into array elements at newlines from a stream which is expected to end in a single NUL byte. If that NUL byte isn't present, `read` will exit with a nonzero status (indicating an error).
  - Putting `&& printf '\0'` on the end of the `aws` command causes a NUL byte to be emitted *if and if the `aws` command succeeded*. In this way, we've ensured that information on whether `aws` succeeded or failed is propagated back to the `read` command; this also is portable to older versions of bash than support the alternative `readarray` or `mapfile` commands.
  - `$( ... )` is preferred over backticks as command substitution, because backticks change the meaning of backslashes and other backticks in them unless that enclosed content changes its quoting. See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst#a_closer_look_at_the_two_forms
- Using `read -r -a < <(...)` instead of `... | read -r -a` is for reasons described in [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024). The syntax in question is also known as a "process substitution", documented at http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst

Comment: This is great, thank you for the comprehensive reply!

One quick question, is there an easy way to cycle through the returned results to process them. A "for" loop for example?

Comment: Glad it helped! If you consider the question closed (not in need of more answers), please click the checkbox up by the top of the answer to mark it accepted.

Comment: The only question I have is is there an easy way to cycle through the returned results to process them. A "for" loop for example?

Comment: `for snapshot in "${snapshots_to_delete[@]}"; do ...`; see [BashFAQ #5](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005) or http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays for more on arrays in bash.